# Are the user ids provided for external members unique for a team

Tags: slack-api

Are all the user ids provided in the API (conversations API and events API) for an external user guaranteed to not collide with any of user ids for the team that the api token is for?

In other words suppose token `Tok1` was obtained when a user installed the app to team `Team1`, and suppose `Team1` has slack connect channels with team `Team2`. Are all the user ids reported for users in `Team2` by the API (when using `Tok1`) guaranteed to not collide with any of the userids for `Team1` or for users from other slack connect channels that `Team1` has?

Also, for events API payloads sent for events on slack connect channels, what does the `team_id` parameter represent in the event? Is it always the other team (`Team2` in this case)?

Answer (score 0):

Literally from https://api.slack.com/methods/users.identity

> User IDs are not guaranteed to be globally unique across all Slack users. The combination of user ID and team ID, on the other hand, is guaranteed to be globally unique.

On the second part. The information is always clear.  Please look at `.inviting_team.team_id`